# Push failed heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I need some help to solve this. I have others websites in another heroku account, but I 'm not getting in my empty account. I am using python3.5.0 (but I tried change python version without sucess) and Django 1.10. I have in my git repositore, runtime.txt, procfile.txt, but I'm having this problem: (terminal)

```
    Counting objects: 105, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (97/97), done.
Writing objects: 100% (105/105), 2.22 MiB | 113.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 105 (delta 34), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.5.0
remote:  !     Requested runtime (python-3.5.0) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to confiam2.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/confiam2.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/
```

How can I solve this? I tried to update heroku version, and change python version. Without sucess. Very thanks who can help me.

Comment: "I tried to… change python version." How did you do this?

Comment: Changing runtime.txt, but  I think I changed to another unsupportable version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error code is this -

```
Requested runtime (python-3.5.0) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
```

If you visit the [support page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support) suggested, you will see that Python 3.6.2 and 2.7.13 are the **only** supported runtimes. Why would you expect 3.5.0 to work? Change your runtime.txt file to contain *python-3.6.2* (or try another version, such as *python-3.5.2*, and maybe it will work. Who knows, it's not supported) and the app should be accepted by Heroku (as long as there are not other, non-related problems).

Comment: I'm getting this error message even in a project with no `runtime.txt` at all (but one which has been upgraded with `heroku stack:set heroku-18 -a <app-name>`). Should I *add* a `runtime.txt`, or is there some way to say "Heroku please pick a Python version for me, I don't care"? [EDIT: I did `git add runtime.txt`, pushed (which worked fine), and then `git rm runtime.txt` and pushed again. Worked great!]

Comment: I just reported to launchpad that pkg.resources==0.0.0 is *still* being inserted, because it just happened to me on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Sadly, taking that line out did *not* make my Heroku push succeed. When I tried checking my support ticket there today, I was told there was something wrong with their API so I wasn't going to be getting an answer so long as that is so. Finally, I tried *every* supposedly supported version in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version. Every single one of them failed with the same message.

Answer (score 1):

Best answer i was found to remove this error is:-
uninstall the  pkg-resources==0.0.0 by pip uninstall pkg-resources==0.0.0 commmand
and run
pip freeze > requirements.txt command
and then
git add .
git commit -m "deleted the pkg from requirements.txt"
git push heroku master

enjoy the day with heroku....

Answer (score 0):

```html
pipenv lock
git add. 
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

If you need a different version edit the new file and enter which version you want. 
Like this:

```html
[requires]
python_version = "2.7"
```

or

```html
[requires]
python_full_version = "2.7.15"
```